# How can I print many pre-existing strings separated by a line?

Tags: python

I'm working on a project and I have a bunch of already defined strings with various names

I want to print all of them, each one starting on a new line. What I have right now is this:

```py
print(line1 + '\n' + line2 + '\n' + line3 ... )
```

Don't get me wrong, it works, but I was just wondering if there was an easier way to do it that would physically shorten the line. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method:

```
>>> line1 = "a"
>>> line2 = "b"
>>> line3 = "c"
>>> "\n".join([line1, line2, line3])
'a\nb\nc'
>>> print("\n".join([line1, line2, line3]))
a
b
c
```

Or, you can use the `sep` parameter of [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) if you don't need to store the string:

```
>>> print(line1, line2, line3, sep="\n")
a
b
c
```